# Apache segfault with passenger

Tags: apache, passenger

I have problem installin passenger under Linux.
The way I'm doning it is

1. Added repository:  `deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list`
2. Installed it:

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libev4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-passenger
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 580 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/273 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 281 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-passenger.
(Reading database ... 287776 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-passenger_1%3a5.0.13-1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-passenger (1:5.0.13-1~trusty1) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-passenger (1:5.0.13-1~trusty1) ...
```

3. Then I tried to enable passenger module with `sudo a2enmod passenger` but for some reason I had `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf` and `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load` files missed after installation. (They are not created and also not removed with `libapache2-mod-passenger` so I suppose this is some kind of a bug). So I created them manually:

s

```
set@set:~$ which ruby
/home/set/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
set@set:~$ which rails
/home/set/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rails
set@set:~$ ll /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ | grep passenger
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1209112 Jul  3 01:35 mod_passenger.so
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf:

```
<IfModule passenger_module>
        PassengerRoot /home/set/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/passenger
        PassengerRuby /home/set/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

and /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
```

4. the module was successfully enabled then but when I was restarting apache it throw me a segfault:

a

```
Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                                               Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

and the coredump:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from apache2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 30116]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007faa58b8e37e in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_begin() const () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
```

So I stuck at this point and have no idea where to move nex. Reinstalling of `libapache2-mod-passenger` does not help. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: since you are using a product that is developped by a company with commercial interest, and their product keeps crashing: how about asking *them* for support?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is more like memory issue.
I am facing something similar as your issue. But my case is happening with the virtual box VM's. A similar setup for me worked on a typical hardware with more RAM.

What I am doing now to fix this issue is to install the latest passenger module.
`gem install passenger` and running `passenger-install-apache2-module` which comes natively with passenger.

and I think the latest module just work.

Here is my **puppetmaster.conf** file entries under **apache conf dir**.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.26/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.26
```